# how to get around a websocket call blocking other websocket calls

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io

I am attempting to perform a constant message from the websocket client to server(python/flask/socketio)

I have a submit button on a simple page that starts off a long running job.

```
$('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('submit', {...});
            return false;
```

In the python code i kick off the long running job like so:

```
@socketio.on('submit', namespace='/namespace')
def long_running_function(message):
    long_running_job_code(message)
```

What I would expect to happen is python to kick off the long_running_job_code and go back to executing the loop in the form of setInterval:

on client the 'loop' :

```
setInterval(function() { pinger() }, 1000);
    function pinger()
    {
       socket.emit('ping','test');
    }
```

on server:

```
@socketio.on('ping', namespace='/namespace')
def ping(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': '.'})
```

Before the submit button is hit, the 'ping' function is placing .... on the screen but it does not continue to perform that function while long_running_job_code is executing.

I believe the issue is blocking on the server side, but I am not sure.  The long running job has emits that are still getting to the client, but the ping emit stops while the long running job is going.

Anyone have an idea on how to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: What loop are you referring to? I don't see a loop. Is your issue blocking on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: The 'loop' in this case is the setInterval(function()...   it emits a ping every 1000 ms

Comment: After letting the long running job finish, the ping emits that were happening while that job was running get dumped to the screen, so it appears to be spooling them until the long running job is done.  The goal is to have it do both at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not mention this, but my guess is that you are using eventlet or gevent as the web server of your application, because that is what makes the most sense when working with WebSocket and Flask-SocketIO in particular.

Eventlet and gevent are coroutine servers. They can handle multi-tasking, but this is done cooperatively. That means that for a context switch from one task to another to occur, the first task must release the CPU. The CPU is automatically released transparently when certain I/O calls are made, like when reading or writing from a socket. You can also explicitly release the CPU by calling the `sleep` function. If a task goes off to do some long calculation without doing any I/O or explicitly releasing the CPU, then the whole thing is going to block.

You basically have two ways to keep the machinery going while you run your long function. One way is to regularly issue sleep calls. When a sleep call occurs, the scheduler will give the CPU to other task(s) before returning from the sleep. If your function has a loop, for example, you can add this on each iteration:

```
eventlet.sleep(0)
```

The other way to not block is to put the long function in a subprocess, which will probably require more changes that just adding sleeps here and there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are correct, I am using flask-socketIO,  This gives me something to go on and I can experiment more to see how best to handle it.